# At which ROC threshold does WEKA calculate TPR?

Tags: weka, roc, auc

I am using WEKA for classification. In results, it shows me TPR for both classes and AUC. Beside 1R (where there is only one point in the ROC curve) I don't understand at which threshold TPR is calculated: 0.50 ? Does WEKA use the same criteria for all algorithms? Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary statistics**

True positive rate (TPR) is simply

```
        true positive
--------------------------------
(true positive + false negative)
```

(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity))

There is no threshold involved.

**NB:** Weka uses instance weights rather than instance counts for calculating metrics. But this only has any noticeable effect when you define instance weights in your dataset. By default, instances will have a weight of 1, which then is the same as using counts.

**ROC curve**

For generating the ROC curve, e.g., in the Explorer, Weka just varies the threshold on the class probability estimates in each case (the ones that the classifier generates). This data is generated through the [ThresholdCurve](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/ThresholdCurve.html) class.

Comment: In a ROC curve, TPR and FPR can assume any value b/w 0 and 1 : <https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016786550500303X?via%3Dihub> In the origin TPR=0 and FPR=0, top right instead TPR=1 and FPR=1; the ideal classifier being TPR=1 and FPR=0. In between, there is a virtually infinite number of possibile values for TPR and FPR, with the notable exception of 1R, where only one point is present. In practice, the curve is calculated for a limited number of points, then interpolation is used. In WEKA, the color of the curve visualizes the different thresholds.

Comment: Here I put two examples of ROC curves: one with 1R and the other with Naive bayes: https://imgur.com/a/dntWv1i  In the second you can see the different color for different classification thresholds. I hope this helps to understand my question.

Comment: Apologies for misreading your post. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I know how WEKA generates the curve. My question: at which threshold is the value of TPR calculated ? Is the default 0.5?